# NextJS pages is undefined

Tags: next.js, shopify-app, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I've got a Shopify app that, on install and on load shows an error for a second or two before it loads okay. The error says "pages is undefined" and originates from NextJS code.
This part to be exact:

```
function resolveDynamicRoute(pathname, pages) {
const cleanPathname = (0, _normalizeTrailingSlash).removePathTrailingSlash((0, _denormalizePagePath).denormalizePagePath(pathname));
if (cleanPathname === '/404' || cleanPathname === '/_error') {
    return pathname;
}
// handle resolving href for dynamic routes
if (!pages.includes(cleanPathname)) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
    pages.some((page)=>{
        if ((0, _isDynamic).isDynamicRoute(page) && (0, _routeRegex).getRouteRegex(page).re.test(cleanPathname)) {
            pathname = page;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
return (0, _normalizeTrailingSlash).removePathTrailingSlash(pathname);
}
```

The error is thrown on the second if statement.
The file is found in /node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js, so I can't go changing stuff to this file.

I figure it has something to do with my dynamic routes, but I can't for the life of me find out what's wrong. Does somebody else know?

My routing:

```
 - /pages
   - _app.tsx
   - index.tsx
   - /customers
     - index.tsx
     - [customerId].tsx
   - /api
     - auth.tsx
     - graphql.tsx
     - /auth
       - callback.tsx
     - /customers
       - data_request.tsx
       - redact.tsx
     - /shop
       - redact.tsx
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

If any more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Check if `resolveDynamicRoute` function always passes the second argument.

Comment: I am running into a similar error (also in a Shopify app), but originating in `_resolveHref` in `next-server/router/router.js (1144:9)`. Any luck solving this @Paul van den Dool?

Comment: No. The error no longer occurred when the app was properly hosted. It only occurred while on localhost so I simply ignore it when it pops up. It disappears quite quickly.